# Splitting a string from a specific point in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have looked at the split string methods in C#, such as:

```
string[] lines = Regex.Split(value, "\");
```

Although I have come across the situation where I need to extract a file name from a file path, so I dont want to have to split the string on all occurrences of "\" e.g.:

```
C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe
```

Expected output:

```
calc.exe
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
new FileInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe").Name
```

Answer (score 4):

Let the framework take the strain. Use the Path.GetFilename method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx